# Dropdown ASPX how to query from a list

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm trying to select from a database UNIQUE ID's and put them into a a list in the dropdown menu I know it seems easy but I'm a little noob.Could you help me. I've tried to interrogate the list somehow but I don't know if it's good then I tried to put it my asp is like this:

```
ID: <asp:DropDownList ID="ProdtID" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

The problem is it isn't showing anything

```
IDataReader ProductId = null;

int n = 300;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    string getProductName = "";
    NameValueCollection coll = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
    objProducts.productname = coll[ProdtID.UniqueID];
    ProductId = this.objProducts.getProductsData();
    this.objUtil.selectBindDs(ProdtID, ProductId, "PickPN", "PickPN_id");
    //Response.Write(NameValueCollection.[0].Value);
    ProdtID.DataSource = ProductID;
    ProdtID.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Off: if you have any influence on it, get rid of web forms  asap.

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx

```
ID: <asp:DropDownList ID="ProdtID" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In your code behind; what this does is load items for use in your aspx page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/14atsyf5(v=vs.85)
        ProdtID.Items.Add(new ListItem("Carbon", "C"));
        ProdtID.Items.Add(new ListItem("Oxygen", "O"));
    }
```